# Arquivo CSV gravado no banco

Tags: php, mysql, array, csv

Tenho um arquivo grande CVS e preciso gravar ele no meu banco de dados
a primeira linha são os campos, que tenho que validar se estão certos e fazer umas alterações por exemplo

primeira linha NOME, DATANASCIMENTO, NOMEMAE
segunda linha GUILHERME FREIRE, 15/02/1987, MARIA CLARA
terceira linha PEDRO ANTUNES, 20/04/1990, PATRICIA SA

Ate ai tudo bem, mas a primera linha pode ser diferente e quero validar isso
ela pode estar como NOMECOMPLETO, DTNASCIMENTO, MAE ... ETC

como faço isso com a melhor eficiência possível?

Comment: Uma outra solução seria que ao invés de você usar o banco relacional,preferisse usar um [nosql dedicado exclusivamente ao formato csv](http://adltecnologia.blogspot.com.br)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode criar o CREATE STATEMENT assim:

```
#!/bin/sh
# pass in the file name as an argument: ./mktable filename.csv
echo "create table $1 ( "
head -1 $1 | sed -e 's/,/ varchar(255),\n/g'
echo " varchar(255) );"
```

Este código shell pega a primeira linha do CSV e converte num create statement dando o nome das colunas com o que tiver na primeira linha, para depois vc executar no mysql.

Ou na mão se não for muitas colunas. Basicamente vc precisa ter a tabela criada com todos os campos que irá precisar.

Depois vc executa essa query no mysql:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/pasta/arquivo.csv' INTO TABLE nome_tabela
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Para mais detalhes consulte a documentação Mysql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html